Moving to python 3.12.2 generates PicklingError during spark dataframe creation
I am not very experienced in spark, spark context elements and handling them... Please advise on the following problem:
I used to run a test involving the creation of a mocked spark context in python 3.9.6 that worked well. Since we moved to python 3.12.2, this code raises an Exception when trying to create a simple dataframe with a schema  (This is a simplified version of my code that raises the same error):
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StructType,
    StructField,
    StringType,
    TimestampType,
)

BODACC_SCHEMA = StructType(
    [
        StructField("siren", StringType(), True),
        StructField("identifier", StringType(), True),
        StructField("nojo", StringType(), True),
        StructField("type_annonce", StringType(), True),
        StructField("date_publication", TimestampType(), True),
        StructField("source_identifier", StringType(), True),
        StructField("data_source", StringType(), True),
        StructField("created_at", TimestampType(), True),
        StructField("updated_at", TimestampType(), True),
    ]
)


spark_session = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("LocalExample").getOrCreate()
spark_session.createDataFrame([], BODACC_SCHEMA)

This is the exception that is raised.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py", line 458, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 602, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 692, in reducer_override
    return self._function_reduce(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 565, in _function_reduce
    return self._dynamic_function_reduce(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 546, in _dynamic_function_reduce
    state = _function_getstate(func)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 157, in _function_getstate
    f_globals_ref = _extract_code_globals(func.__code__)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 334, in _extract_code_globals
    out_names = {names[oparg]: None for _, oparg in _walk_global_ops(co)}
                 ~~~~~^^^^^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 894, in createDataFrame
    return self._create_dataframe(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 938, in _create_dataframe
    jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 3113, in _to_java_object_rdd
    return self.ctx._jvm.SerDeUtil.pythonToJava(rdd._jrdd, True)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 3505, in _jrdd
    wrapped_func = _wrap_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 3362, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 3345, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/data_pipelines/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py", line 468, in dumps
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range

I am using pyspark==3.3.0.
Why is this happening, how can I fix it?
Edit : I tried with pyspark==3.5.1 aswell, and it's not working either. (See Edit 2)
Edit 2 : Running this code in fact with python==3.12.2 & pyspark==3.5.1 "simply" does not produce an error. The first time it did was because I ran it through debugpy and that apparently interferes with pickling somehow.... I don't fully understand the details of this yet, if somebody can explain why it worked on prior versions of python (even through debugpy) and doesn't anymore, I'd really appreciate it.
P.S This code is simplified to illustrate the problem, what I am doing in reality is sending a packaged .tar.gz of my code via dagster to an EMR Serverless app that is running pyspark code. There is certainly a parallel between debugpy and the way this code is running through EMR...

Looks like python 3.12 is not supported yet.

"We've changed the Python version to 3.10 for Spark versions < 3.4"

So, in a nutshell:
pyspark==3.5 for python 3.11
pyspark<3.4 for python 3.10

Is bitnami relevant here? Is that from official spark devs?

I figured...My spark pipelines are screwed.
